# Reset running total when value from reference table is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a view where its query is a running total of another view. As we all know, running total will continue to do sum regardless if the reference table/view is equal to zero. In my case, I would like to reset the running total when the reference view has a value of zero. I'm a bit new to SQL Server so I don't know how to approach this..

To better understand my question, here's my reference view (for this example, I created it as a table) where I will compute the running total:

```
Create table Net_Cash(
  ID int IDENTITY  primary key,
  MO int,
  YR int,
  LC decimal(6,2)
);


insert into Net_Cash values  
                            (1, 2011, 56.23),
                            (2, 2011, 881.4),
                            (3, 2011, 195.09),
                            (4, 2011, 522.9),
                            (5, 2011, 0),
                            (6, 2011, 355.66),
                            (7, 2011, 0),
                            (8, 2011, 344.86);
```

[image]

Here's my running total query:

```
SELECT        
    MO, 
    YR, (sum(LC) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO)) AS LC
    FROM            
    Net_Cash
```

Result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

I want the LC column to reset to zero (reset running total) if the LC column of Net_Cash is zero.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign groups to the data.  You can do so by counting the number of `0`s before each row:

```
SELECT MO, YR, 
       SUM(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO) AS LC
FROM (SELECT nc.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO) as grp
      FROM Net_Cash nc
     ) nc;
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Thanks @GordonLinoff! It's my first time to encounter the syntax PARTITION BY and I have no idea what does it do. Will study it more for future references. Thanks again!

Comment: Btw @Gordon-Linoff, what if I want to add a constant value if LC is not zero?

I tried this:
SELECT MO, YR, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ((SUM(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO)) + 12)) AS LC

but it doesn't work.

SELECT MO, YR, 
       (SUM(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO) + 12) AS LC

This returns the value 12 when LC is zero.

Thanks in advance for the help!