# Add numbers with PARTITION BY and ORDER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a case where I want to add a number in a running total statement. [My running total statement is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196792/reset-running-total-when-value-from-reference-table-is-zero/66196814#66196814) (I asked this hours ago because my running total needs to be zero when its reference value is zero).

I tried numerous steps but I'm stuck..

Here's my data:

```
Create table Net_Cash(
  ID int IDENTITY  primary key,
  MO int,
  YR int,
  LC decimal(6,2)
);


insert into Net_Cash values  
                            (1, 2011, 56.23),
                            (2, 2011, 881.4),
                            (3, 2011, 195.09),
                            (4, 2011, 522.9),
                            (5, 2011, 0),
                            (6, 2011, 355.66),
                            (7, 2011, 0),
                            (8, 2011, 344.86);
```

[image]

Here's the running total query where running total will return zero if its reference value is zero:

```
SELECT MO, YR, 
       SUM(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO) AS LC
FROM (SELECT nc.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO) as grp
      FROM Net_Cash nc
     ) nc;
```

Here is the result:

[image]

However, I want to add a constant value in my running total LC when LC is non zero. I tried different approaches but it's all wrong..

```
SELECT MO, YR, 
       (SUM(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO)) + 10 AS LC
FROM (SELECT nc.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO) as grp
      FROM Net_Cash nc
     ) nc;
```

Result (10 is still added when LC is zero):

[image]

Try 2 (this has an incorrect syntax according to SQL Server):

```
SELECT MO, YR, 
       SUM  (CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
            SUM(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO) + 10
            ) AS LC
FROM (SELECT nc.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO) as grp
      FROM Net_Cash nc
     ) nc;
```

Try 3 (this has an incorrect syntax again according to SQL Server):

```
SELECT MO, YR, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 0 ELSE LC + 10) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO) AS LC
FROM (SELECT nc.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO) as grp
      FROM Net_Cash nc
     ) nc;
```

It's all wrong. I don't know how to add it properly..

Here is the current output and the expected output:

Current:

[image: Current output]

Edited: Expected:

[image: Expected output]

Edited: 10 is not added in month 6 and 8 because the running total has been reset. The +10 will only be applicable on the first running total.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edited: My + 10 value will only be added to the first (non zero) running total. Since my running total will be reset, the + 10 won't be added to the running total after reset. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE expression in your query which will add `10` only in the rows of the first group:

```
SELECT MO, YR, 
       SUM(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO) + 
       CASE WHEN grp = 0 AND FIRST_VALUE(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO) <> 0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END AS LC
FROM (
  SELECT nc.*,
         SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO) as grp
  FROM Net_Cash nc
) nc;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7829a1d0abd4b6dc7a87cdc85bab3f4a).
Results:

| MO | YR | LC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2011 | 66.23 |
| 2 | 2011 | 947.63 |
| 3 | 2011 | 1142.72 |
| 4 | 2011 | 1665.62 |
| 5 | 2011 | 0.00 |
| 6 | 2011 | 355.66 |
| 7 | 2011 | 0.00 |
| 8 | 2011 | 344.86 |

Comment: Hello @forpas! Thanks for this!
So I applied it in my true tables but I noticed something unexpected.. 10 is also added on the on the previous LC value of the first non zero running total.

I'm not sure how to explain this in words but here is a sample: in the given test data above, if we replaced LC of Month 1 with zero, and then applied the query. LC of month 1 will now be 10. 

It seems like it add 10 to the previous zero value LC of the first non zero running total.

Comment: @cerulean you did not mention in your question that the first month could have 0 in LC too. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again @forpas! I applied the changes and I don't know why but it just won't add 10. I tried changing `WHEN grp >= 0 OR` but it won't reflect. I also played around with the demo and added data but I can't replicate the changes to my db. My first non zero LC is on grp 145. I tried changing the query to `WHEN grp = 145 OR` but I don't why it's not adding 10. Anyway, thanks for all the help! Maybe I'll get back to you for some questions.

Comment: @cerulean I only know the data that you posted in your question. Use my demo with your actual data to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional sum in the outer query:

```
SELECT MO, YR, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 10 ELSE LC END) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO) AS LC
FROM (SELECT nc.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO) as grp
      FROM Net_Cash nc
     ) nc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16559e8f072d035fcac16c4c80bac276) is a db<>fiddle.

If you only want the value on the "0" row, then put the `case` outside the `sum()`:

```
SELECT MO, YR, 
       (CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 10
             ELSE SUM(LC) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY YR, MO)
        END) AS LC
FROM (SELECT nc.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN LC = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YR, MO) as grp
      FROM Net_Cash nc
     ) nc;
```

Comment: Hello again Gordon! Tried this (and this is a bit similar to my first attempt) but it's not my expected output, it gives the value 10 when LC is zero. What I would like is to add 10 in the running total (non zero).

Comment: @cerulean . . . This produces your expected output.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hello @Gordon! Thanks for this fiddle. But the non zero line has an added 10 value. Also, I my question is a bit wrong and confusing.. I would like to only add 10 to the first non zero running total. Since the running total resets to 0 when LC is 0, the new running total after won't be added by 10 anymore. (I edited my question, sorry for the confusion)